# onCreateOptionsMenu content persist between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-optionsmenu

I have an ViewPager with 2 fragments. Fragment 1 and Fragment 2. They both override the simplest possible onCreateOptionsMenu()

Fragment1

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1, menu);
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    return;
}
```

Fragment2

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment2_actionbar, menu); 
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    return;
}
```

The content of the menu xml files:

R.menu.fragment1

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:title="sdfsdf"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_download_all"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/menu_download_all">
    </item>

</menu>
```

R.menu.fragment2_actionbar:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_add"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

The strange thing is. The fragment1 xml menu ("sdfsdf") is shown the ViewPager is on fragment1 - only! The fragment2 menu (@string/menu_search) is shown all the time. Both when the viewpager shows the fragment1 or fragment2.

I have no idea how to debug this. All ideas are welcome.

EDIT: I should perhaps mention that when I go to fragment1 I can see that onCreateOptionsMenu() in both fragment 1 and 2 is executed, and when I go to fragment2 only onCreateOptionsMenu() in fragment2 is executed. So i makes sense that the menu is displayed as it is. However, why could it be that onCreateOptionsMenu() in fragment 2 is executed when I select fragment1?

Comment: why commented `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);` line?

Comment: No real reason other than I read that someone suggested it a as a fix. I have added it back without any effect

Comment: You can use supportinvalidateoptionmenu(); method for changing the menuitems by getting the state of viewpager fragment.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?